# Как поделить entity на 2 DataSource

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Нужно чтобы инсерты происходили в мастер БД, а чтение происходило из реплики. Как организовать?

Между БД настроена репликация. Сейчас используется spring + jpa + repository. `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` и `JpaTransactionManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Если вкратце, то вам необходимо создать два EntityManager(или же DataSource) и в разных случаях обращаться к соответствующему менеджеру. Как конкретно это делать можно поискать в интернете, вариантов много и они обычно завязаны на то, как у вас уже реализовано. Вот пример с [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2311663/1646082)  или же [официальный пример от Spring Data](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources)